# How do i set the download destination of my WebView to the Downloads folder without knowing the name of the file?

Tags: android, webview, download, android-download-manager

I have the following problem:

I have a `WebView`. This `WebView` has a download listener that acts when the user is trying to download a file.

I want the file to be downloaded to the regular "Downloads" folder. I can do this by using

`request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title);`

But how do I save the file under its original name?

I can't use

```
String name = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, mimetype);
```

Since the url that is being called does not contain the filename.

My download manager currently looks like this:

```
mainWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            // Show a download notification
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            String title = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, mimetype);

            // Set directory of where the file should be saved to
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title);
            // Start the download
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
}
```

Note: I am currently using the `URLUtil.guessFilename()` Method because that will allow me to save my file, event if it's under the wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The solution was passing the proper `contentDisposition` to the `URLUtil.guessFileName()` Function.

Getting the title works like this:

```
String title = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
```

(All parameters are passed into the `public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)`)